# Get Spring profile name with spring EL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Consider a web based application with spring 4. The spring bean profiles is defined in web.xml like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>prod,edb,cas</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now consider a bean is defined in spring-applicaiton-context.xml as

```
<util:properties id="myPolicy"      
    location=
      "classpath:/configs/${ACCESS-ACTIVE-PROFILE-SECOND-ITEM}/my-policy.properties" />
```

Is it possible that I can access the list of active profiles and select the second one (in my example edb). In this way I can make my resource load dynamically  when active profile changes.

---

This may help! I could get the active profile when web application starts with below code:

```
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event){
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
        String activeProfiles[] = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles();
        system.out.print(activeProfiles[1])
    }
```

Comment: what if the profile order changes? you shouldn't use index to get the required profile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax would be `"#{environment.activeProfiles[1]}"` - however, it's too early in the context life cycle; the activeProfiles is not set up before the SpEL is evaluated in this case.

What's wrong with

```
<beans profile="foo">
    <util:properties id="myPolicy" 
          location="classpath:/configs/foo/my-policy.properties" />
</beans>

<beans profile="bar">
    <util:properties id="myPolicy" 
          location="classpath:/configs/bar/my-policy.properties" />
</beans>
```

?

Actually, I just found that

```
"#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[1]}"
```

works - explicitly calling the getter causes the property to be loaded.

Comment: Great!! Well I considered that I can only use placeholder in XML. As mentioned in http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/spring-property-placeholder-configurer-a-few-not-so-obvious-options.html in  But you have shown that I can easily call  springEL in my xml file. Can you show me the reference ?!

Comment: `${...}` in spring configuration XML are property placeholders, `#{...}` are SpEL expressions. See [the Spring Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef). These expressions are evaluated once, at context initialization time. Other projects, such as [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) use SpEL expressions at runtime, where the expression is evaluated against the current message. It's important to understand the differences.

Comment: Yes it mentioned there: **SpEL expressions can be used with _XML_ or annotation-based configuration metadata for defining BeanDefinitions. In both cases the syntax to define the expression is of the form #{ <expression string> }**

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html
There is acceptsProfiles method to check if some profile list is active, which is very usefull with SpEL.

Comment: Calling the getter to load the property was useful for my usecase.

Comment: `"#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[1]}"` didn't work for my case. The array was empty yet.

Comment: It is pointless to comment on 7+ year old answers, especially when other users found success with it, even recently; something is obviously different with your situation; ask a new question with many more details.