# How to implement OR logic for spring qualifiers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have following configuration:

```
@Qualifier1
@Qualifier2
@Bean
public MyBean bean1(){...}

@Qualifier2
@Qualifier3
@Bean
public MyBean bean2(){...}

@Qualifier1
@Qualifier2
@Qualifier3
@Bean
public MyBean bean3(){...}

@Qualifier3
@Bean
public MyBean bean4(){...}

@Qualifier1
@Bean
public MyBean bean5(){...}
```

And it is the injection place:

```
@Qualifier2
@Qualifier3
@Autowired:
private List<MyBean> beans;
```

By default spring uses `AND` logic for each `@Qualifier`

So `bean2` and `bean3` will be injected.

But I want to have `OR` logic for that stuff so I expect beans `bean1` `bean2` `bean3` and `bean4` to be injected

How can I achieve it?

### P.S.

`@Qualifier` annotation is not repeatable so I have to create meta annotation for each annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Qualifier1 {
}
```

Comment: are you sure the description is correct? `So bean2 and bean3 will be injected` vs `so I expect beans bean1 bean2 bean3 and bean4 to be injected`

Comment: @Eugene could you elaborate? AR is **So bean2 and bean3 will be injected** But I WANT another behaviour

Comment: @Eugene  I want to inject bean if it has at least one matching qualifier

Comment: are you saying that if a certain based based on `QualifierX` has already been loaded into the context, you don't want _another_ bean with the same `QualifierX` to be loaded into the context?

Comment: @Eugene I want all beans

Comment: @gstackoverflow Is it possible to add multiple `@Qualifier` to a `@Bean` method?

Comment: @Madhu Bhat, good question beacause Qualifier is not repeatable but you can create META annotation and it is possible at this case. Modificating the question

Comment: How abount `@Profile` + SPEL [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449014/get-spring-profile-name-with-spring-el](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449014/get-spring-profile-name-with-spring-el) `@Qualifier` is used to resolve ambiguity, not to "abuse" with complex logics

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What if you used marker interfaces instead of qualifiers? For example:

```java
public class MyBean1 extends MyBean implements Marker1 {}

public class MyBean2 extends MyBean implements Marker2 {}

public class MyBean12 extends MyBean implements Marker1, Marker2 {}
```

Then using this:

```java
@Bean
public MyBean1 myBean1() {
    //...
}

@Bean
public MyBean2 myBean2() {
    //...
}

@Bean
public MyBean12 myBean12() {
    //...
}
```

and this:

```java
@Autowired private List<Marker1> myBeans;
```

You would get a list of `myBean1` and `myBean12` beans.

And for this:

```java
@Autowired private List<Marker2> myBeans;
```

You would get a list of `myBean2` and `myBean12` beans.

Will this work?

**UPDATE I**

***Custom FactoryBean***

I implemented [TagsFactoryBean](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-tags-factory-bean/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/demo/TagsFactoryBean.java) class and [@Tags](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-tags-factory-bean/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/demo/Tags.java) annotation which you can use to solve your task (I hope :)).

First, mark your beans with `@Tags` annotation:

```java
@Tags({"greeting", "2letters"})
@Bean
public Supplier<String> hi() {
    return () -> "hi";
}

@Tags({"parting", "2letters"})
@Bean
public Supplier<String> by() {
    return () -> "by";
}

@Tags("greeting")
@Bean
public Supplier<String> hello() {
    return () -> "hello";
}

@Tags("parting")
@Bean
public Supplier<String> goodbye() {
    return () -> "goodbye";
}

@Tags("other")
@Bean
public Supplier<String> other() {
    return () -> "other";
}
```

Then prepare `TagsFactoryBean`:

```java
@Bean
public TagsFactoryBean words() {
    return TagsFactoryBean.<Supplier>builder()
            .tags("greeting", "other")
            .type(Supplier.class)
            .generics(String.class)
            .build();
}
```

Here `tags` is an array of desired tags whose beans should be selected, `type` is a selected beans type, and `generics` is an array of generic types of the beans. The last parameter is optional and should be used only if your beans are generic.

Then you can use it with `@Qualifier` annotation (otherwise Spring injects all beans of `Supplier<String>` type):

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("words")
private Map<String, Supplier<String>> beans;
```

The Map `beans` will contain three beans: `hi`, `hello` and `other` (their name are keys of the Map and their instances are its values).

More usage examples you can find in [tests](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-tags-factory-bean/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/cepr0/demo/TagsFactoryBeanTest.java).

**UPDATE II**

***Custom AutowireCandidateResolver***

Thanks to @bhosleviraj [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57247433/5380322), I implemented [TaggedAutowireCandidateResolver](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-tagged-autowire-candidate-resolver/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/resolver/TaggedAutowireCandidateResolver.java) that simplifies the process of autowiring the desired beans. Just mark your beans and the autowired collection with the same tags and you will get them injected into the collection:

```java
@Autowired
@Tags({"greeting", "other"})
private Map<String, Supplier<String>> greetingOrOther;

@Configuration
static class Beans {
   @Tags({"greeting", "2symbols", "even"})
   @Bean
   public Supplier<String> hi() {
      return () -> "hi";
   }

   @Tags({"parting", "2symbols", "even"})
   @Bean
   public Supplier<String> by() {
      return () -> "by";
   }

   @Tags({"greeting", "5symbols", "odd"})
   @Bean
   public Supplier<String> hello() {
      return () -> "hello";
   }

   @Tags({"parting", "7symbols", "odd"})
   @Bean
   public Supplier<String> goodbye() {
      return () -> "goodbye";
   }

   @Tags({"other", "5symbols", "odd"})
   @Bean
   public Supplier<String> other() {
      return () -> "other";
   }
}
```

You can use not only the Map for injecting beans but also other Collections.

To make it work you have to register a `CustomAutowireConfigurer` bean in your application and provide it with `TaggedAutowireCandidateResolver`:

```java
@Configuration
public class AutowireConfig {
   @Bean
   public CustomAutowireConfigurer autowireConfigurer(DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
      CustomAutowireConfigurer configurer = new CustomAutowireConfigurer();
      beanFactory.setAutowireCandidateResolver(new TaggedAutowireCandidateResolver());
      configurer.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
      return configurer;
   }
}
```

More usage examples see in this [Test](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-tagged-autowire-candidate-resolver/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/cepr0/resolver/TaggedAutowireCandidateResolverTest.java).

Comment: I want to Autowire by  several markers. In your case I want Autowire all beans which implements interfaces Marker1, Marker2. So looks like your approach is not applicable for my topic

Comment: I need smth like @Autowired private List<Marker2 or Marker1> myBeans

Comment: At this case I had to declare @Bean for each combination of tags I need

Comment: @gstackoverflow It is a question or a statement? )

Comment: It is statement)

Comment: I would like to mark List by Tags annotation only without additional configuration

Comment: @Cepr0 Glad to know that you found a way to implement it using CustomAutowireResolver. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Answer requires deep understanding of how autowiring resolution is implemented in Spring, so we can extend it. 
I couldn't come up with any solution yet, but I can give you some pointers.
Possible candidate to extend is **QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver** , override method that resolves to a qualified bean. And pass the custom autowire resolver to the bean factory. 
You can clone source code and correct version branch from here: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework

There is a **CustomAutowireConfigurerTests** in **spring-beans** module, that might help you understand few things.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't do it by using annotation.

What I'd use is the `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware` Maybe you need to write some extra code but in this way you can solve your issue.

I'd implement a class like this:

```
@Component
public class SpringContextAware implements ApplicationContextAware {
    public static ApplicationContext ctx;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        ctx = applicationContext;
    }
    public static synchronized ApplicationContext getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

Then in all beans where you need the OR logic you want you can do something like this:

```
@Autowired
private SpringContextAware ctxAware;
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    //Here you can do your OR logic
    ctxAware.getCtx().getBean("qualifier1") or ctxAware.getCtx().getBean("qualifier2") 
}
```

Will this solve your issue?

Angelo

Comment: This will work I believe but it is a bad design. You will have tight coupling between spring and your business logic

Comment: Yes.... other solution would be to create a custom annotation and use the AOP in order to create your OR logic